# How to move JIRA issues to Testlink?

Tags: jira, testlink

Hi Experts,
             I need of move the JIRA Issues into TestLink for Report generation. 
I explored and found TestLink to JIRA integration is available as Bug Tracking.

But my need is to create "Link from JIRA to TestLink" [for move data from JIRA to TestLink"].